# How do I prevent me from changing /etc/hosts

Tags: etc

I'm trying to fight  my bad habit of wasting time on time-consuming websites such as reddit/liveleak etc.

The only thing which seems to work is adding a line like this to my etc/hosts
127.0.1.1 www.reddit.com

It works for a few days but then when i got nothing to do i edit this file and remove this line and start wasting my life again.

Is it a way to make my etc/hosts file immune to changes that would delete something from it ? (So that i would only be able to add things to it when i stumble upon a website which i think is a potential threat for my time).

It is really important for me and i will be extremely grateful for any help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu but with you getting a spine ;) Want you want is impossible and it totally up to your mentality.

Comment: Naa you want to add to a file ... that means you can always remove lives. Impossible to enforce. Only you yourself can enforce yourself (or hire someone to stand next to you with a stick ;) )

Comment: @Gero1913 How about finding a compromise ? You could spend some time on the websites and then spend some doing something productive. You've also said "when I've nothing to do". How about finding a hobby ?  Like, language learning or . . . .answering questions and helping people here, on askubuntu ? "Nothing pacifies the mind as having steady purpose" (Marry Shelley, Frankenstein)

Comment: Why do you change your question and make of it an answer?

Comment: Several related questions (with answers) were asked [on the Personal Productivity site](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/4540/how-to-avoid-procrastinating-on-the-stack-exchange-network).

Comment: I had the same problem. 
The system needs hosts file, so you can't encrypt it or anything else.
I added firewall to the router, changed the password of the router to some string leaving some symbols known. I've also saved the hash of the password, so if I indeed have to log in to router I can bruteforce it in several hours.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Unfortunately, your self-control cannot be configured.

---

If you want to prevent yourself from editing this file, it will not be possible as long as you are logged in with your administrator account (sudo rights). Create a new user without administrator privileges and work with this account.

Or by editing the configuration of your router and forbid it from that side.

Comment: and forget the admin password and forget you can reset it anytime you want? :P